# Unable to connect to GCE using different google accounts

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have two google accounts and 1 Compute Engine Instance. I ssh to it from browser using two different account. Then i run the following command:

`sudo gcloud compute ssh myinstance`

It succeeds on account1 and fails on account2 with the following error:

`Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.`

I can even run 
`sudo gcloud compute ssh account2@myinstance` when login as account1 and it succeeds.

How to make `gcloud compute ssh` command on account2 executable?

Similar thing happens when i try to configure shh keys using `config-ssh` command. I can use `ssh myinstance` on account1 and get the following error on account2:

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname myinstance: Name or service not known`

Maybe the problem is that account1 is the creator of instance

Comment: run it without `sudo`?

Comment: i run all commands with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot adding metadata to compute engine of account2